# JWT Авторизация в микросервисах

Tags: spring, микросервисы

Допустим, у меня есть два сервиса: `user-service` и `hospital-service`.

`user-service` занимается регистрацией новых пользователей, генерирует JWT access и refresh токены, валидирует токены и авторизирует пользователей добавляя их в `SecurityContext`.

`hospital-service` занимается работой с пациентами и врачами в базе данных. Работник регистратуры и врач имеют разные права доступа. Например врач не может добавлять новых врачей, в то время как работник регистратуры может.

Получается есть две группы пользователей, *врачи* и *работники регистратуры*, присваиванием этих ролей также занимается `user-service`.

Как связать два этих сервиса, чтобы `hospital-service` знал какой сейчас пользователь к нему обращается и понимал можно ли давать ему определенные данные или нет?

Answer (score 0):

в payload JWT можно отправить метку role1: "doctor".
тогда hospital-service принимая эту метку поймет, на что есть права, а на что нет.

Comment: Куда он будет ее принимать?

Comment: сервис hospital-service будет принимать токен как таковой, ему будет доступен header и payload (если эти два сервиса обменяются ключами, которыми подписывается сообщение).

Comment: Тогда `hospital-service` будет извлекать токен из заголовков запроса, валидировать и брать из токена нужную информацию, но что если у меня будет больше сервисов, тогда мне в каждом писать одну и ту же логику?

Comment: 1х) сервис авторизации может выдавать ID-роли - для скорости. В целом, ничего плохого в этом нет. НО: если вариативность полномочий большая, то ..

2) можно выдать краткий ID набора полномочий и по нему еще раз сходить либо в сервис полномочий либо в реплицированную таблицу (группу таблиц) в локальном сервисе. Цель этого краткого ID в этом случае - только собрать набор всех разрешенных и запрещенных действий.

Answer (score 0):

можешь в hospitalService получить авторизованого юзера
`final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`